# Unterminated template literal in MVC razor

Tags: javascript, razor, datatable

I have the following code which poulated datatable dynamically:

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var table = $('#orders').DataTable();

            for (let item of @Model.ItemList) {

                table.row.add({
                    "id": item.id,
                    "product.name": item.product.name,
                    "quantity": item.quantity,
                    "linetaxes": item.linetaxes,
                    "discount": item.discount,
                    "lineitemtotal": item.lineitemtotal
                }).draw();
            }
        });

    </script>
```

When I run it, i get the following error message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unterminated template literal
>
> for (let item of
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Myproject.Models.LineItem])

Can someone tell me how to fix this? Hoe else can I access the Model in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@Html.Raw` and `Json.Encode` for your viewmodel property collection object which has type of `List<LineItem>`:

```
for (let item of @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ItemList)) {

            table.row.add({
                "id": item.id,
                "product.name": item.product.name,
                "quantity": item.quantity,
                "linetaxes": item.linetaxes,
                "discount": item.discount,
                "lineitemtotal": item.lineitemtotal
            }).draw();
}
```

By using `Model.ItemList` without `Json.Encode`, it implicitly calls `ToString()` on page render which returns fully-qualified name of the object, i.e. `System.Collections.Generic.List<Myproject.Models.LineItem>`.